# Using IMultiValueConverter for unit of measurements conversion

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application user needs to be able to select units of measurement for some input fields from a drop-down menu:

[image]

The model that stores user inputs has two properties, one for the input value (always in SI system units, in this case - kg), and another to store the selected unit type:

```
public class InputProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    
    private double _value;
    private MassUnits _selectedUnit;

    public MassUnits SelectedUnit 
    { 
        get { return _selectedUnit; }
        set { _selectedUnit = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUnit)); }
    }
    public double Value 
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value)); }
    }
}
```

`MassUnits` is an enum with descriptions which are later used for displaying in ComboBox:

```
public enum MassUnits
{
    [Description("g.")]
    grams,
    [Description("kg.")]
    kilograms,
    [Description("t.")]
    tons
}
```

The viewModel looks like this:

```
public class PhysicalDataViewModel
{
    public PhysicalData PhysicalData { get; init; }
    public List<MassUnits> MassUnits { get; } = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MassUnits)).Cast<MassUnits>().ToList();

    public PhysicalDataViewModel(PhysicalData physicalData)
    {
        PhysicalData = physicalData;
    }
}
```

And the WPF part:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MassValuesTextBox">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <local:MassUnitsConverter x:Key="MassUnitsConverter"/>
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MassUnitsConverter}">
            <Binding Path="PhysicalData.Mass.Value" />
            <Binding Path="PhysicalData.Mass.SelectedUnit" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MassUnits}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PhysicalData.Mass.SelectedUnit}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Initially I wanted to use traditional binding for TextBox, but apparently it is impossible to bind `ConverterParameter` to `PhysicalDataViewModel.Mass.SelectedUnit`, which is absolutely required for the converter in order to apply the correct conversion. So instead I opted for MultiBinding, since it was the only working example I could find ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078820/implementing-imultivalueconverter-to-convert-between-units)). My converter looks like this:

```
public class MassUnitsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private MassUnits massUnit;

    private Dictionary<MassUnits, double> unitRatios = new()
    {
        { MassUnits.grams, 1000 },
        { MassUnits.kilograms, 1 },
        { MassUnits.tons, 0.001 }
    };

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double val = double.Parse((string)values[0]);
        massUnit = (MassUnits)values[1];
        double conversionRatio = unitRatios[massUnit];
        return (val * conversionRatio).ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double val = double.Parse((string)value);
        double conversionRatio = unitRatios[massUnit];
        return new object[] { (val / conversionRatio) };
    }
}
```

While this works, I have to add `MassUnitsConverter` as a resource for every single TextBox (and there are many like this one), because if I add it as a resource for the window, all the TextBoxes share the same instance of it, and therefore also share the value of `massUnit` field, which of course breaks everything.

This solution feels more like a hack than a proper solution, but I've done my research as best I could and I can't find anything better. Can anyone please tell me what is the proper way to implement such unit conversion? Or perhaps there is a better way than using `IMultiValueConverter` at all? Apologies if there are fundamental mistakes in my implementation. I am still quite new to WPF and I am not sure how to do it properly.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I know I can use `x:Shared="false"` for that converter, but it still doesn't feel like this should be the appropriate implementation. Surely there must be a better way.

Comment: IMHO, adding a property of the calculated value in consistent unit such as gram to your InputProperty is more natural because I guess you will need such value somewhere else and providing such value could be responsibility of that class.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  The MultiBinding approach with `x:Shared="False"` is a total hack;  I've done it.  There are a few places where I could not avoid it.  But I don't like it anymore than you do.

A better approach might be a dedicated user control that contains both the `TextBox` and Unit `ComboBox`.  Call it the `MassConverterControl` or something like that.  It can do the conversions for you in response to user interaction with the `TextBox` and `ComboBox` control.  You can just write event handlers and `DependencyProperties` so that it can be re-used anywhere.

I've struggled with all the unit conversion WPF bindings myself.  One thing that will help you tremendously -- maybe not in this specific case but in many -- is a dedicated class that ties together the `MassUnits`, the `double` value and all the conversions needed.  One that exposes properties for each unit you might want to convert it to.

The simple way to do this is to add a NuGet package like [UnitsNet](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet) to your project.  It will give you every unit conversion under the sun.

When I needed to do this found I needed make my own version for unrelated reasons.  So I created some simple classes to represent Length, Area and Volume.  I could have done it for Mass as well if I had wanted.  It looks roughly like this

```
public class Mass
{    
    public Mass(double value, MassUnits unit)
    {
    }
    private static double ConvertTo(MassUnits unit)
    {
        // Logic here that looks at the current value and unit and
        // does the math to return it to the given unit.
    }
    public double   Value { get; set; }
    public MassUnits Unit { get;  set; } 

    public double Kilograms => ConvertTo(MassUnits.Kilograms);
    public double Grams     => ConvertTo(MassUnits.Grams);

    public static Mass FromGrams(double grams) => new Mass(grams, MassUnits.Grams);
    public static Mass FromKilograms(double kg) => new Mass(kg, MassUnits.Kilograms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking of combining unit types with conversion values, and UnitsNet seems a great way to do it. As for the first suggestion, is it correct to use even handlers for this? I thought in MVVM one should always use bindings instead? I also thought that since unit conversion is purely View concern (different units are used nowhere except on UI), doesn't it violate MVVM pattern to invade Model with UI concerns as in your last example? I am new to MVVM so I might be wrong, feel free to correct me.

Comment: MVVM is an architecture for constructing applications that makes tasks like binding in WPF easer.  Until it doesn't.  In this case, you are not changing the model at all.  You are just writing custom UI handling in the view so that it can present what you need (and return it to bound clients) in the proper format. 
 That's one of main reasons for writing controls in the first place.  It's great when you can bind this using existing controls but sometimes, for some complicated tasks, you need a dedicated control and some code-behind.  Just whatever you do, try to make the control re-usable